# How to copy files from a bucket using gsutil from within a container on GCE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, gsutil

I have a container running within GCE kubernetes engine which is trying to copy some data from a bucket to a mounted persistent disk:

```
gsutil -m rsync -r -d "gs://${DB_BUCKET}/db" /db
```

When the container runs, it fails with the following message:

```
AccessDeniedException: 403 xxx-service@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to my-bucket-db-data
```

If I look at the service account, it does appear to have permissions to view storage buckets.  I create a populate this bucket as part of my deployment process if that makes any difference.

What permissions do I need to grant/how to be able to sync the data from the bucket across?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add referred permission to `xxx-service@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com`:

Follow this steps:

1) Access *Permissions* tab into ${DB_BUCKET}

2) Search for your service account in the search input field

3) In the *Role(s)* column find "Storage Object Viewer" role